# Fatal exception main: a method does not work

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception

When i run my application on my device there is this error:
LOGCAT

> 07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831): Process: com.example.findmycar, PID: 1831
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo{com.example.findmycar/com.findmycar.activity.PosizioneAttualeActivity}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at com.findmycar.activity.PosizioneAttualeActivity.onLocationChanged(PosizioneAttualeActivity.java:264)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at com.findmycar.activity.PosizioneAttualeActivity.onCreate(PosizioneAttualeActivity.java:86)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   07-15 14:09:00.808: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):    ... 11 more

here there's the .java

```
package com.findmycar.activity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.findmycar.R;
import com.findmycar.activity.MainActivity.erroreDialogFragment;
import com.findmycar.activity.MainActivity.simulaLoginDialogFragment;
import com.findmycar.data.Posizione;
import com.findmycar.data.PosizioniDAO;
import com.findmycar.utility.Session;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactoryimport   com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PosizioneAttualeActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

TextView posizioneAttualeWellcome ,latText, lngText, descrizioneText, statoText; 
Button parcheggia, riparti;
LocationManager locationManager;
String provider, username = "";
float lat ,lng ;
Posizione attiva = null, attuale = null;
Location location;
private PosizioniDAO posizioniData;
private GoogleMap FMCMap;

List<Marker> listaMarkerStorico = new ArrayList<Marker>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    boolean logged = false;



    if(Session.containsPreference(getApplicationContext(), "username")){
        logged = true; 
        username = Session.getPreference(getApplicationContext(), "username");
    }
    else {
        Log.i("my_security", "l'utente non ha il permesso di accedere a questa vista");
        Intent i = new Intent(PosizioneAttualeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.posizione_attuale);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!enabled) {
        gpsDialogFragment l = new gpsDialogFragment();
        l.show(getFragmentManager(), "gpsDialogFragment");
    } 

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
      provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
      location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

    onLocationChanged(location);

    FMCMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.PosizioneAttualeMapfragment)).getMap();

    FMCMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    setUpView();
}

public void setUpMarker(Posizione posizione){

    LatLng location=new LatLng(Double.valueOf(posizione.getLat()),Double.valueOf(posizione.getLng()));

    Marker marker = FMCMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(posizione.getDescrizione()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.logoattivo)));

    if(posizione.getStato()=="1"){

        marker.remove();

        Marker markerNonAttivo = FMCMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(posizione.getDescrizione()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.logononattivo)));

        listaMarkerStorico.add(markerNonAttivo);

    }


}
public void setUpView(){
    posizioniData = new PosizioniDAO(this);
    posizioniData.open();

    attiva = posizioniData.getPosizioneAttiva(username);

    posizioneAttualeWellcome = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.posizioneAttualeWellcomeTextView); 
    latText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.latTextView); 
    lngText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lngTextView);
    descrizioneText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.descrizioneTextView);
    statoText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.statoTextView);

    parcheggia = (Button)findViewById(R.id.parcheggiaButton);
    riparti = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ripartiButton);

    if(attiva == null ){
        attiva = new Posizione();
        attiva.setDescrizione("Vuoi Parcheggiare qui ?");
        attiva.setLat("");
        attiva.setLng("");
        attiva.setStato("1");

        latText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        lngText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        statoText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        parcheggia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        riparti.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    else {
        latText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lngText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        statoText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        parcheggia.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        riparti.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        setUpMarker(attiva);
    }

    posizioneAttualeWellcome.setText("la Tua Posizione attuale Ë lat:"+lat+", lng: "+lng+" "+username);

    latText.setText(attiva.getLat());
    lngText.setText(attiva.getLng());
    statoText.setText(attiva.getStato());
    descrizioneText.setText(attiva.getDescrizione());

    OnClickListener parcheggiaListener = new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.i("my_log", "cliccato parcheggia "+v.getId());

            attiva.setLat(String.valueOf(lat));
            attiva.setLng(String.valueOf(lng));
            attiva.setUtente(username);

            posizioniData.creaPosizione(attiva);


            setUpView();


        }
    };
    parcheggia.setOnClickListener(parcheggiaListener);

    OnClickListener ripartiListener = new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.i("my_log", "cliccato riparti "+v.getId());

            posizioniData.ripartiDaPosizione(attiva);

            setUpView();


        }
    };
    riparti.setOnClickListener(ripartiListener);
}
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    lat = (float) (location.getLatitude());
    lng = (float) (location.getLongitude());

    setUpView();
  }
}
```

I suppose that the problem is referred to the method onLocationChanged(), in fact the errors into the logcat of lines 86 and 264 are referred to these lines:

line 86

```
onLocationChanged(location);
```

line 264

```
lat = (float) (location.getLatitude());
```

Comment: Please include the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code you provided is very long and confusing. It's difficult to locate where the error is. Additionally, we don't even know what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Perhaps `location` is null?

Comment: Yes, it must be. `location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);` Presumably `getLastKnownLocation` can return `null` and this code doesn't check for that. Yup. Confirmed in the documentation for [getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate` method you get the last known location for the provider and call `onLocationChanged`, but according to the [documentation for getLastKnownLocation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)):

```
Returns
 the last known location for the provider, or null
```

You need to check whether the location is `null` either before calling `onLocationChanged` from your `onCreate` method, or in your `onLocationChanged` method (or both).